# Mysql order by date which in format month(string). day(number), year(number)

Tags: php, mysql

I have a field containing dates in this format example: **Feb. 15, 2020** and I need to order the results DESC by this field, but it is saved as a **VARCHAR** and I cannot change this. Is there a workaround?

I have tried STR_TO_DATE to order in mysql query but didn't work as expected..

Thanks for any help and advice in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`STR_TO_DATE()` can work with correct format and punctuation marks according to the value. In your case of date value `Feb. 15, 2020`, the correct `STR_TO_DATE()` format is:

```
STR_TO_DATE("Feb. 15, 2020", "%b. %d, %Y");
```

Whereby:

| Format | description |
| --- | --- |
| %b | Abbreviated month name (Jan to Dec) |
| %d | Day of the month as a numeric value (01 to 31) |
| %Y | Year as a numeric, 4-digit value |

If the data consistently stored in that format of:

| month | day | year |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Feb. | 05, | 2020 |
| 3 character month abbreviation | both 05 or 5 are acceptable | 4 digit year (but it seems to work with 2-digit year based on the fiddle below) |

Then the above `STR_TO_DATE()` function is sufficient. If some of the months have full month name like `June.` instead of `Jun.`, then the function for `%b` will not work for that column.

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d70750b6d524f9b4cfa5f8c01169208b